# Django - Get "total" between two elements in HTML in real-time using a script

Tags: javascript, python, django

I know this question has being done here a lot but I looked and tried a lot of answers, wasn't able to retrieve what i need.

First, I pass a value from an item using django forms through the view. In this example, the template receive the value of "900" because I use the default {{form.price}} in HTML .

```
<input type="text" name="price" value="900" readonly="readonly" id="id_price">
```

Inside the same HTML i have a field to manually insert a quantity:

```
<input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity">
```

And the final input to show to multiplication between those two

```
<input type="text" name="total" id="total">
```

As a script I used this (saw the answer in a question but i wasn't able to recreate the result in my "total" input)

SCRIPT

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('').keyup(function () {
        var multiplyAndShow = function () {
            var val1 = parseFloat($('#id_price').val())
            var val2 = parseFloat($('#quantity').val())
            val3 = val1 * val2 || "Some Text"
            $("#total").html(val3)
        }
        $("#id_price").keyup(function () { multiplyAndShow(); });
        $("#quantity").keyup(function () { multiplyAndShow(); });
    });
});
</script>
```

The script is not been used because when I set a quantity it doesn't make a thing in real time.  The price value is readonly so i don't know if that's the problem.

I'm a newbie in javascript so any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the value of the `total` field, not the `html`. Change the following line

```
$("#total").html(val3)
```

to

```
$("#total").val(val3)
```

You should also change the `$('')` to `$(document)`.

Comment: Additionally, instead of defaulting the value to “Some Text”, put that “Some Text” in the placeholder HTML property and make the val be “”. This way your text box is blank, but still displays your placeholder text. It’ll be styled better and likely make things easier for you. And it’ll definitely be more intuitive to the user.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!  It's working now!  Marked as accepted!